# not able to launch EC2/VPC via terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

am trying to integrate terraform with aws, aws cli configured and I do have admin, completeEC2 access, configured terraform/aws plugins.

I can create a ec2/vpc from console or from aws cli but when am trying to invoke through terraform, am getting authorization error like below

I tried decoding the error message and adding debug log but no luck.Any help would be great! thanks

```
action=DescribeAccountAttributes&AttributeName.1=supported-platforms&Version=2016-11-15
-----------------------------------------------------: timestamp=2022-05-05T17:49:28.788-0500
2022-05-05T17:49:29.160-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.12.1_x5: [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response ec2/DescribeAccountAttributes Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

022-05-05T17:49:29.160-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.12.1_x5: [aws-sdk-go] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>UnauthorizedOperation</Code><Message>You are not authorized to perform this operation.</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>e****</RequestID></Response>: timestamp=2022-05-05T17:49:29.160-0500
2022-05-05T17:49:29.160-0500 [DEBUG] provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.12.1_x5: [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Validate Response ec2/DescribeAccountAttributes failed, attempt 0/25, error UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
        status code: 403, request id: ea***: timestamp=2022-05-05T17:49:29.160-0500
2022-05-05T17:49:29.160-0500 [WARN]  provider.terraform-provider-aws_v4.12.1_x5: Unable to get supported EC2 platforms: UnauthorizedOperation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to create a programmatic access user for the terraform
2. Among others (e.g. scoped-ec2) need to add the following statement to your user IAM policy:

```json
    {
      "Sid": "AllowDescribeEC2Params",
      "Action": [ "ec2:DescribeAccountAttributes" ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": [ "*" ]
    }
```